# Can Hall sensors be placed externally in a small BLDC motor?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm trying to build a closed loop control for a BLDC motor with the use of Hall effect sensors. The problem is that I can't find a sensored BLDC motor at all in my country. All the available BLDC motors are for drones. Is there a way to take a non-sensored BLDC motor like [this](https://robu.in/product/a2212-10t-13t-2200kv-brushless-motor-with-soldered-connector/) and add [Hall sensors](https://www.amazon.in/Solvo-ERickshaw-sensor-genuine-quality/dp/B0B5K7XVMY/ref=pd_rhf_d_dp_s_ci_mcx_mr_hp_d_sccl_1_7/262-0360479-9479433?pd_rd_w=OfHvr&content-id=amzn1.sym.ec85d1e0-b01c-479f-9f1b-0340b8d2be63:amzn1.symc.1b44a113-f80b-4bad-946d-45e84e3d8ccf&pf_rd_p=ec85d1e0-b01c-479f-9f1b-0340b8d2be63&pf_rd_r=HPCR8Y6GZWEKZ2C2FKZV&pd_rd_wg=YHCWH&pd_rd_r=7df2b30e-23ed-4c29-9f8c-75a7232c171d&pd_rd_i=B0B5K7XVMY&psc=1) externally? I'm going to use only small BLDC motors.  Would this be possible or should I look into sensorless FOC control?

[image: BLDC Motor small without sensors]